# Как мне подключить функций и объекты находящиеся внутри файла в разных папках?

Tags: python

Я запускаю файл находящийся в директории.

```
python/folder/test_1.py
```

И мне нужно получить функций из файлов test_2.py и test_3.py

Но способы которые я пробовал не работают.

```
#python/folder/test/test_2.py
from test.test_2 import fun_1, fun_2, fun_3
#python/test_3.py
sys.path += ['~/python'] 
from test_3 import fun_1, fun_2, fun_3
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Можете попробовать sys.path.append(path). И какая конкретно у вас ошибка выдаётся?

Comment: И вы так и пишете sys.path.insert(1, '/.../') ? Или вставляете путь до директории?

Comment: @dmitryklemenkov я пробовал оба способа и оба выдают что модуль не найден.

Comment: а что со вторым вопросом, на счёт '/../' ?

Comment: @dmitryklemenkov Файл из которого я запускаю код находится в директории `python/folder/test_1.py` а один из файлов находится на папку выше основного файла `python/test_3.py` а команда `/.../` ищет файл на папку выше относительно основного файла. в html это вроде так работало.

Comment: Причём тут HTML? У вас иерархия файлов неправильно разработана. Это ошибка дизайна, и всякими хаками не лечится.

Comment: присоединяюсь к вопросу "Причём тут HTML?", укажите просто название папки. В вашем случае sys.path.insert(1, 'test')

Comment: @dmitryklemenkov @0andriy Иногда случается так что файл к которому нужно подключится находится далеко от корневого файла в соседной папке под папке и так далее.  Вот и интересно как к нему подключится в python. HTML пример я привел как ближайший к моему пониманию пример работы с  директорией файлов.  Например нужно перетащить код из файла c директории `python/folder_1/test_1.py` В файл `python/folder_2/test_2.py` для этого нужно отдать команду поднятся к папке python `/.../` относительно файла test_1.py а после спустится `/folder_2/test_2.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Измените имя папки** `test`, например на `testing`, и ваш первый импорт `from testing.test_2 import fun_1, fun_2, fun_3` будет в Питоне 3.3+ работать.

   Имя `test` для пакета *опасно,* т.к. это имя регулярного пакета — папки `Lib\test\` в папке вашей инсталляции Питона, и потому что папка `Lib` автоматически находится в списке `sys.path` (который команда `import` осматривает), ваш пакет `test.test_2` будет Питон искать *не в вашей* папке test, a в своей `Lib\test\`:

   ```
   >>> import test
   >>> test.__path__
   ['C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\test']
   ```
2. **Для Питона до версии 3.2 включительно:**

   Добавите файл с именем `__init__.py` (может быть пустой) в папки `python`, `folder`, `testing`, `test2`, `test3`, чтобы Питон узнал, что эти папки содержат пакеты.
3. **Для всех версий Питона:**

   Перед командой `from test_3 import fun_1, fun_2, fun_3` добавите путь к папке, в которой находится папка `test3`, например

   ```
   sys.path += [r'C:\Users\user\python']
   ```

Comment: Я не знаю почему но sys.path почему то не работает я добавил во все папки файл `__init__.py` появилась папка `__pycache__` в папке `test` единственное что работает это test.test_2 но sys.path никак на это не влияет.

Comment: Вы работаете в Линуксе? Какая версия Питона?

Comment: Window Python 3.7.6

Comment: Ой, в моем ответе я для примера применил пути в Линуксе. Исправите, пожалуйста, это приблизительно так: `sys.path += [r'C:\python\folder', r'C\python']`. Когда ваша папка `python` находится ниже в структуре папок, используйте соответствующие полные пути. (Файлы `__init__.py` не нужны, но могут быть.)

Comment: А можно ли использавать не строгие пути к файлу?`r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\python'` потому что если мне надо будет перенести программу в другую папку то придется переписывать это раз за разом.

Comment: Можно написать тоже релятивные пути, но это другой вопрос - в первую очередь проверите, если это работает с полными путями.

Comment: Да работает `sys.path += [r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\python\folder\test' ,r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\python']`

Comment: единственное что я смог придумать `import os 
string = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
spl_string = string.split('\\')
rm = spl_string[:-1]
listToStr = '\\'.join([str(elem) for elem in rm])`

Comment: Имя `test` для пакета опасно, т. к. `import test` будет импортировать папку `lib\test`, которая находится в пути инсталляции Питона.

Comment: Для переносимости лучше всего иметь `test_2.py` и `test_3.py` в той же самой папка как `test_1.py`.